# Getting an std:bad_alloc when trying to replace existing variables with variables read from a file using fread

Tags: c++, crash, fwrite, fread

I'm having issues with implementing a simple save/load function to a game of chess. The saving appears to work fine as it creates a non-empty file (and doesn't crash the game). The loading, however, always crashes. After trying to debug it a bit it seems to work fine and load the file contents (correctly, after checking the buffer variable), but it crashes when trying to replace the old variables with the loaded ones. I'm trying to replace the current turn with the old turn and the game data (chessboard and the like) to the old game data.
As soon as it tries to execute the last 2 lines of the update function, it crashes the game and gives me an std:bad_alloc crash without further info.
The game itself is a project we need to finish, but this feature wasn't required at all and I just wanted to try and see if I could implement it :). Anyone have a clue as to how to fix it?

This is my save function:

```
void MainWindow::saveGame(){
saveData saveGameData;
saveGameData.savedGame = g;
saveGameData.savedTurn = turn;

FILE * pFile;
saveData buffer[] = { saveGameData };
pFile = fopen ("save.bin", "wb");
fwrite (buffer , sizeof(saveData), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
fclose (pFile);
}
```

This is my load function:

```
void MainWindow::loadGame(){
saveData* tempSaveData;
game tempGame;
zw tempTurn;

FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
saveData * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen ( "save.bin" , "rb" );
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

// obtain file size:
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (pFile);
rewind (pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (saveData*) malloc (sizeof(saveData)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

// the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer.

// terminate
fclose (pFile);
free (buffer);

tempSaveData = buffer;
tempGame = tempSaveData->savedGame;

}
```

This is the saveData struct:

```
struct saveData {
speelbord   savedBord; // speelbord (= chessboard class, in dutch).
zw          savedTurn; // black or white enum. 
};
```

Speelbord is a vector< vector < positie > >

positie is a class, one tile on the board being saved as a position.

zw is an enum with white and black as options.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing `saveData`, but complex objects, non-POD, cannot be `malloc`ed `write`ed or `read`ed safely. Take a `std::string` for example. A `string` is often a couple of pointers and some book-keeping. This has to be initialized correctly or the pointers are likely to go boom. If you `write` a `string` to a file, you wrote the pointers, not the data pointed at. You read it back later and you get pointers to Crom knows what. That's a ticking timebomb.

Comment: Anyway, if you want an answer, we need to see `saveData`. A [mcve] would be even better, because when you build a MCVE the error is often revealed to you in all its buggy glory, making it easy to pick off and fix.

Comment: Unrelated: `saveData buffer[] = { saveGameData };` is redundant. You can use `&saveGameData` to get a pointer with much less fuss. Possibly related, `fwrite (buffer , sizeof(saveData), sizeof(buffer), pFile);` writes far more data than you actually have. The second parameter is the size of the object you want written and the third is the number of objects to write, so instead of writing one buffer, you wrote `sizeof(buffer)` `buffer`s. Whoops.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now we need definitions of `speelbord` and `zw` so we know what's in them and likely to cause problems.

Comment: Also just noticed that you `free (buffer);` before you `tempSaveData = buffer;` You can't safely assign from memory that you just released. You will have to move the `free` to after you use `buffer`.

Comment: Alright, I'll move the free(buffer); and will be editing to provide the speelbord and zw definitions/

Comment: Moving the `free` may solve all of your visible problems. By the way, rather than using `malloc` and `free` strongly consider using a `std::vector` or a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: A `vector` cannot be `write`n to a file without help. Like the `string` example above, a `vector` is typically three pointers (data buffer, end of data in buffer, and end of data buffer) and these pointers, not the data pointed at, is stored to the file and likely will not be valid when the file is read back.

Comment: Search keyword: Serialization.

Comment: As far as I understand, C++ doesn't provide any serialization? And if possible, I'd prefer a method without the use of databases or such.

Comment: Depends on what you want. C++ has to-text conversion for most simple objects via the `>>` operator. Binary serialization is trickier because there are no guarantees on byte order (endian) or even the size of integers. The writer of the program has to determine how numbers, strings, lists, etc... are to be interpreted by defining a communication protocol.

Comment: Is there perhaps a small piece of example code you could show me as to how to do this? I don't need anything special for this function, just storing a struct and reading that same struct back and then using it. The buffer (when checked in the variables panel whilst debugging) shows me that it actually has the save-loaded data in it, properly named and everything.